# how to override draw(rect ) function in UIView Swift?

Tags: swift, uiview, draw

if I want to create a custom UIView with a custom shape I should override draw function right?

but I don't understand how it works it has no return values where should I send my bezier path to?

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
// after I create my bezier path what should I do inside to have my custom view drawn?

}
```

thank you in advance for the anwers

Comment: Note that usually you don't want to override `draw(_:)`. It's usually better to do something like add a CAShapeLayer to the view that contains the path you want to draw. See my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52802176/value-of-type-cashapelayer-has-no-member-leadinganchor/52802254#52802254 for a custom UIView that has a CAShapeLayer as its content layer and draws a path as the view's content.

Answer (score 6):

Fill/stroke the path. Example:

```
class MyView1 : UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let p = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:100,height:100))
        UIColor.blue.setFill()
        p.fill()
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. Not sure why this was down voted. It answers the question.